# angular form : select value with button

Tags: angular

I have a angular form and I would like to be able to select a value when my user click on a button. How to do it ?

page.html

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; index as i">
    <button (click)="chooseProduct(i)">{{product.name}}</button>
</div>
```

page.ts

```
form: FormGroup;
booking: Booking;
products: Product[];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private params: NavParams,) {

  this.form = formBuilder.group({
        [...]
    product: [params.get('item') ? this.booking.product : '',Validators.required],
        [...]
  });

}

chooseProduct(i) {
    ???
}
```

Comment: `this.form.get('product').value = this.products[i]`? It would be simpler if you passed the product as argument, rather than its index. And I don't really understand why you put the product in a form group in the first place. What's the point?

Comment: Building off @JBNizet's response, `chooseProduct(product)` might make things a bit easier.

Comment: Yes for sure ! And because it is really useful and easy for the other parts of my form. I'll try what you just said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `product` so every time you click the button you will get the 'product' object related to that button

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;">
    <button (click)="chooseProduct(product)">{{product.name}}</button>
</div>
```